# Using variable in list

Tags: django, django-templates

```
<h4>{{ description.header.1 }}</h4>
```

It's work (displays element in list).

numberSeason -- int variable.

How use variable?

`<h4>{{ description.header.numberSeason}}</h4>` or `<h4>{{ description.header.{{ numberSeason }}</h4>` -- does not work.

Comment: If its a list then `{{ description.header.1.numberSeason }}`

Comment: Might want to take a look at [`for`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) loops

Comment: you'll need to write a custom tag for this, it's not something django template tags support.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to write your own template filter, something like:

```
# templatetags/myfilters.py

from django.template import Library

def get_list_item(value, index):
    return value[index]

register.filter(get_list_item)
```

Then in the template:

```
{% load myfilters %}

{{ description.header|get_list_item:numberSeason }}
```